# Powershell Syntax issue using LINQ

Tags: powershell, linq, exchangewebservices, contacts

I am trying to write some code that will update a contact list using EWS API.
I grab the list of users using ADSI searcher, then I pull the current contacts from a mailbox using EWS API.

Next I use LINQ to compare the differences. I see if there are users that need to be imported as well as any users that need to be deleted because they no longer exist.

Here is my code

```
#Get Users

$objSearcher=[adsisearcher]""
$objSearcher.Sort.PropertyName = "sn"
$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(extensionAttribute2=DynamicDistro)(|(mobile=*)(telephonenumber=*)))"
$colProplist = "extensionattribute2","initials","mobile","telephonenumber","GivenName","sn","DisplayName","Company","title","mail","department","photo","samaccountname"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i) | out-null }
$Users = $objSearcher.FindAll()

#Get Contacts

$Contacts = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UPN/contactFolders/$folderId/contacts?`$top=999" -Headers $headers -Method Get

#Create 2 variables

#Store User Emails
$A = $($Users.properties.mail)
#Store Contact Emails
#$B = $($Contacts.value.emailAddresses::address)
$B = ($Contacts.value.emailAddresses) | %{$_.Address}

<#
Check differences Between the 2
See if there are any "new" users that need to be added
See if there are any users that need to be deleted because they no longer exist in Add
#>

#Displays what accounts we need to import
$NeedsToBeAdded = [string[]]([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$a, [object[]]$b))

#Displays what acocunts we need to delete because they no longer exist
$NeedsToBeDeleted = [string[]]([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$b, [object[]]$a))
```

Everything works above, but the trouble I am running in to now is the values that are stored in `$NeedsToBeAdded` and `$NeedsToBeDeleted` I need to do stuff with. The issue is, that these values only hold the user email address, and I need to process an import using the contact ID.

So then I try do a foreach-object {} loop and something like this:

```
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UPN/contactFolders/$folderId/contacts?$filter='emailAddresses/address eq '$_'&$count=true" -Headers $headers -Method Get).value
```

(Keep in mind I use Get as the method just for output), once it works, I would change the method to Delete to process the delete.
Now the code above I use should be able to get me that contacts ID info based on the output and value(s) stored in $NeedsToBeDeleted, however for some reason it prints out several users that don't even match that filter.

For example if I want to filter out with using a user ID like billy bob. I changed a couple of values, but this is the layout of the contact Output when I outoput everything without any filtering.

```
id                   : someLongID
createdDateTime      : 2021-06-02T02:54:47Z
lastModifiedDateTime : 2021-06-02T02:55:11Z
changeKey            : changeKEY
categories           : {}
parentFolderId       : parentfolderID
birthday             : 
fileAs               : Bob, Billy
displayName          : Billy Bob
givenName            : Billy
initials             : B.B.
middleName           : 
nickName             : 
surname              : Bob
title                : 
yomiGivenName        : 
yomiSurname          : 
yomiCompanyName      : 
generation           : 
imAddresses          : {}
jobTitle             : 
companyName          : 
department           : 
officeLocation       : 
profession           : 
businessHomePage     : 
assistantName        : 
manager              : 
homePhones           : {}
mobilePhone          : 
businessPhones       : {}
spouseName           : 
personalNotes        : 
children             : {}
emailAddresses       : {@{name=Billy Bob (bbob@domain.com); address=bbob@domain.com}}
homeAddress          : 
businessAddress      : 
otherAddress         :
```

I hope this makes sense and hopefully someone can assist me please. Thank you.

Comment: `::` is for accessing _static_ members. Change `$Contacts.value.emailAddresses::address` to `$Contacts.value.emailAddresses.address`

Comment: Doing that will result in this:
System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Address(int )

Comment: I editted my code. Initially, when I made the change you requested, then I got the error I posted above, but I found a way for it to display properly. I added the change in the original post. I'm still having trouble figuring out how to reference the ID for the user associated in the returned value for those 2 variables.